# How to prevent data from lost when restarting the database?

Tags: oracle, kubernetes-pod, persistent-volumes

I use db as pod with file storage.
the issue is when I stop and start the DB pod, data is lost
and I have to recreate tables

How to resolve it please

Comment: Do you have used `PVC`?

Comment: yes PV/PVC already configured

Comment: can you share your pod's yaml ?

Answer (score 0):

PVC will do the JOB for you. But which storage class are you using ?

And Reclaim Policy of volume plugin.

For your reference:
in PV.yaml
persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Recycle

From K8s Docs:
**Reclaim Policy**

Current reclaim policies are:

**Retain** -- manual reclamation

**Recycle** -- basic scrub (rm -rf /thevolume/*)

**Delete** -- associated storage asset such as AWS EBS, GCE PD, Azure Disk, or OpenStack Cinder volume is deleted
Currently, only NFS and HostPath support recycling. AWS EBS, GCE PD, Azure Disk, and Cinder volumes support deletion.

From Kubernetes Docs:

For volume plugins that support the **Delete** reclaim policy, deletion removes both the PersistentVolume object from Kubernetes, as well as the associated storage asset in the external infrastructure, such as an AWS EBS, GCE PD, Azure Disk, or Cinder volume. Volumes that were dynamically provisioned inherit the reclaim policy of their StorageClass, which defaults to Delete. The administrator should configure the StorageClass according to users' expectations; otherwise, the PV must be edited or patched after it is created. See Change the Reclaim Policy of a PersistentVolume.

reference:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/